# C++ OpenGL - Get the world coordinates of objects (needed for collision detection)

Tags: java, c++, opengl, collision-detection

Im kinda new to OpenGL, but here is my problem :

I'm currently writing a world creator (for Lego Duplo Blocks) and i made my blocks in 3dsmax, then exported them to .obj file. Then i created a parser to parse the file. I basicly put everything in a glNewList. Then for every legoblock i've some parameters (containing the values in wich they should translate over te x and z axis (y axis not yet)) wich i use to alter their position after the list gets called (the blocks move by using the arrowkeys).

Now when creating a new block i want to create some form of collision detection so that when the new block comes on a position that's already taken by an other block, the block automaticly goes on top of that other block (so translating it over the y-axis).

Is there a way to get your world coordinates of a certain object ? Or is there another, better, way to do what i try to do ?

Please help me out here !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL has no idea what you are talking about. It just sees independent vertices and polygons. You need to do these calculations yourself using the data from your model. OpenGL is about visualization. Everything else needs to be done by your application.

The common approach is to store each object with its current position and rotation in your application. Then -- in your draw loop -- you simply iterate over all objects and translate and rotate them independently (usually helpful here: `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()`).

Comment: But i use glCallList to call my list, after doing this i place my camera right and i translate the object(s) depending on the variables for both transX and transZ (or left,right arrowkey and up,down arrowkey). So basicly the only values i know are the ones i put in the glList... Is there a way to get those values after rotating and translating them etc ? Becouse now im stuck on the fact that i have no idea what the values of my polygons are in the world (becouse of the translations made by my arrowkeys)

Comment: @Madsen: OpenGL is a very low-level wrapper for your graphics hardware. It is not supposed to do anything that complex like collision detection. It just tells the GPU what to do. Rotations and translations only affect the current OpenGL matrix. You do not need to worry about them. Think of a cube on your desk. The cube's position does not change, even if you change your viewing angle. That is the case in OpenGL, too. The coordinates remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

What is important here is: **you need to have your data model well-defined independently of OpenGL**. So all the blocks, their positions, rotations, etc- all of this need to be kept in your memory and updated by your CPU code.

Then it gets simple: *you **send** your data to OpenGL and have it rendered.* Not the other way round: you don't *retrieve* the information about objects' position from GL. OpenGL is not a storage place for your logic's data.

Comment: So if i get you right, i need to calculate every object's new position myself (becouse in the beginning when adding ever new block it's gets plotted in the middle after wich i translate them over the x,z axis)? And are there easy ways to do this ?

Comment: Just store the current (x,y,z) values and the rotation in each block.

Comment: I indeed have the starting x y z values and the values over which i translate/rotate for each object... but how can i combine both to receive the new values ? or isn't this nessacary ? i now get that OpenGL doesn't store the data, but i'm still kinda stuck on finding a solution on my problem

Comment: @Madsen: You do not need to recieve "new" values. They are only used for visualization. Your objects remain at the exact same position. You do not need to worry about translation/rotation or any other matrix manipulation.

Comment: Yet how i can then make my collision detection ? becouse all my object (let's say for instance 5 2x4 legoblocks) will have the same x y z polygons for all 5 blocks ?

Comment: Then think how to design your data model so that every instance of a 2x4 block would have its own correct x,y,z. Then just send those data to OpenGL and that's it.